# Can ANT start restart jobs on remote servers?

Tags: java, deployment, ant

Is it possible to have ANT restart your java application on a remote server from a build script? If so any pointers to where that might be defined?

I'm using ant now to push the new code over to the remote server but I still have to login to actually restart the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`<sshexec>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html) you can do pretty much anything on a remote machine (assuming it's got an sshd running). If you don't want to worry about authenticating the ssh session every time, you can set up RSA keys.

```
<sshexec host="remotehost" username="remoteuser" command="/restart/application/command"/>
```

Heed the statement at the beginning of the above link:

> This task depends on external libraries

You'll need to grab [JCraft's JSch jar](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/index.html) and put it on Ant's classpath.